# Arranging ArrayList of Strings with quicksort not working correctly

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, quicksort

I have an `ArrayList` composed of Strings all in lower case with no unique characters. I want to arrange this `ArrayList` in alphabetical order and I attempted so using "quicksort," however I noticed a problem in which my `lo` doesn't calculate correctly after the algorithm places the first pivot acquired in the correct location.

For instance if my array is composed of `a, d, e, c, a` after my quicksort places the pivot `a` in its correct position and begins to sort the other side of array it begins at `e` instead of `d` causing the result to be `a, d, a, c, e`.

Code:

```
    private ArrayList<String> sort(ArrayList<String> ar, int lo, int hi){
        if (lo < hi){
            int splitPoint = partition(ar, lo, hi);
            sort(ar, lo, splitPoint);
            sort(ar, splitPoint +1, hi);
        }
        return ar;
    }

    private int partition(ArrayList<String> ar, int lo, int hi){
        String pivot = ar.get(lo);
        lo--;
        hi++;
        while (true){
            lo++;
            while (lo<hi && ar.get(lo).compareTo(pivot) < 0){
                lo++;
            }
            hi--;
            while (hi>lo && ar.get(hi).compareTo(pivot) > 0){
                hi--;
            }
            if (lo<hi){
                swap(ar, lo, hi);
            }else {
                return hi;
            }
        }
    }
```

Method were algorithm is called:

```
    public Document(String fName){
         ArrayList xa = loadFile(fName);
        sort(xa, 0, xa.size() - 1);    
    }
```

I tried debugging this numerous times but I keep getting lost at the part were the compiler starts going up the stack tree. Why is my `lo` one value higher than needed? What is causing this?

Swap method:

```
   private ArrayList<String> swap(ArrayList<String> ar, int a, int b){
        String temp = ar.get(a);
        ar.set(a, ar.get(b));
        ar.set(b, temp);
        return ar;
    }
```

Note: I start with pivot at position `0`

Comment: Can I suggest you put some logging into your application to see what is going on.

Comment: It looks like you forgot to swap the pivot with hi after the while loop.

Comment: Assuming this is a learning exercise, it is quite instructive to follow your code with pen and paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must consider the equal case inside the partition method.
You only have to change the second while like this:

```
while (hi>lo && ar.get(hi).compareTo(pivot) >= 0){
```

Comment: That makes sense. I forgot to take that into consideration.